# Jquery validation plugin errorplacement for single element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-validate

i am using Jquery validation plugin for validating the form.when validating the form for one element alignment is not proper.

If you see the image,for the city field **icon +** button alignment not proper when it validating the form. Because label error validation is displaying in between the input element and **icon +**. I need to display the error message below of the element.

[image]

My html code is like this for the city field

```
    <tr>
        <td align="right"><span class="mandetry">*</span> City:</td>
         <td>
       <div class="input-group" id="app_details">
      <input type="text" class="form-control client_city" name="client_city" id="city_name" value="<?php echo set_value('client_city')?>"> 
     <span class="input-group-btn">
     <a class="btn btn-default" id='addnewcity' href="<?php echo base_url('addnewcity')?>"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></a>
     </span>
   <div id="messageBox"></div> <!-- Here i would like to display message-->
    </div> </tr>
```

js code is like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#add_client').validate({
    errorClass: 'validation_errors',
    debug: false,
     rules: {
         client_name:{required:true},
         client_address:{required:true},
         client_city:{required:true},
         errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                if (element.attr("name") == "client_city" )
                {
                    error.appendTo("#messageBox");
                }
            }
     },
     messages: {
         client_name:{required:"The Client name is a required / mandatory field"},
         client_address:{required:"The Client address is a required / mandatory field"},
         client_city:{required:"The City is a required / mandatory field"},

     }

});
     });
```

Error message not appended to **messageBox div**.Is there any wrong with **errorPlacement** in js. For only **city** element i need to display the error message properly. For other form fields it shouldn't change.i am unable to solve this issue. Please suggest me. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing the else part, if it is not the `client_city` element then you need to insert the error after

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#add_client').validate({
        errorClass: 'validation_errors',
        debug: false,
        rules: {
            client_name: {
                required: true
            },
            client_address: {
                required: true
            },
            client_city: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            console.log('dd', element.attr("name"))
            if (element.attr("name") == "client_city") {
                error.appendTo("#messageBox");
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element)
            }
        },
        messages: {
            client_name: {
                required: "The Client name is a required / mandatory field"
            },
            client_address: {
                required: "The Client address is a required / mandatory field"
            },
            client_city: {
                required: "The City is a required / mandatory field"
            },

        }

    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wqdg130c/)

Comment: I added `else` condition. Still no result. If i inspect the html message displayed in between fields

Comment: If i use `errorLabelContainer: "#messageBox"` all element validation messages appended to `messageBox`. But i dont want like that.

Comment: you placed the `errorPlacement` inside the `rules` object, that is wrong